# ng-switch only 1 row in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a ng-repeat and each row has a edit button.
When the user click on the edit button. The row will change it's element using ng-switch

For example:

```
<div>{{sample.name}}</div>
change to
<input type="text" ng-model="{{sample.name}}">
```

But I cannot figure out how to switch only the row I clicked.

Here is the [not working fiddler](http://plnkr.co/edit/01EZGhOYzADZmq9tCvfQ?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have only a single global variable `selection`.  One option would be to add a selection variable to each `datas` entry.  Or, you could write a directive with it's own scope (make sure to specify an isolate scope) that handles the switch piece of this- then each scope would have it's own `selection`.

Comment: Thanks.  I figure out using this. http://plnkr.co/edit/01EZGhOYzADZmq9tCvfQ?p=preview


not sure if any side effect.

Comment: Great.  The one thing I'd consider is that by hiding the variable within the controller and then using a getter function you gain the benefits of encapsulation.  Either way it looks like you're set though!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach wont work, because 'ng-switch-when' accepts only primitive strings and can not be evaluated.